# Xamarin full screen grid

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a table made from Grid. I made it in landscape mode. But I wanna see it full screen. Data is always changing so I always want it to fit to my screen. How can I make it so? I tried with grid `VerticalOptions` and `HorizontalOptions` `FillAndExpand` but did not work. What else can I do?

1st page table: https://prnt.sc/10pbhys

```
<Grid x:Name="gr2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1.5"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1.2*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1.5"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

2nd Page Table: https://prnt.sc/10pbiu2

```
<Grid x:Name="gr2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1.5"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1.5"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

My definitions must be like that. (I add boxview for lines of table with 1.5 width)

Comment: With a screenshot about what it looks like now and definition of the parents element of GridView would be better.

Comment: @mxmissile okay i edit it

Comment: A Grid should fill it's container unless you specify otherwise - but a Grid without any content is going to appear empty

Comment: @Shaw I put photos about it.

Comment: Are there always 4 columns but dynamic rows (are you repeating the GridView instead of rows)? Count the number and calculate could work, but using "*" won't do. At least define the width of first column should work. And what about the long text, wrap them or cut the tails? How about tens of rows or column, do you still intend to fit them in one page?

Answer (score 0):

For first question. By play with grid. you have to know that asterisk `*` is mean the rest of screen. If you have 4 asterisk that mean the rest of screen will divide into same size with in 4 area (that's can be row or column).
So logically it will fit to screen by put minimum one asterisk in `RowDefinition` and `ColumnDefinition`.

For better design i recommends to use `RowSpan` property. It will help you in some case. And FYI, grid support layering system. So u can have component behind other component. and for make this happens, you have to use `RowSpan` so the layered component can be seen.

Please review this code `<RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>`. I don't know why you put asterisk after `1.5`.

For second question. I've done this work by assign a scroll view base on desired grid row and column.
Example

```
<ScrollView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
    <!-- this area is scrollable -->
</ScrollView>
```